# How to "Enable textmate links" in NewRelic

Tags: ruby-on-rails, performance, textmate, newrelic

I use the service NewRelic for monitoring rails applications. In the `newrelic.yml` file, there's the following option (that's commented out by default):

```
# Enable textmate links
# textmate: true
```

How do I enable this and what capabilities does it give me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That'll give you links in the stack traces that appear in Developer Mode (`http://localhost:3000/newrelic`). Those links will open the relevant source file in TextMate.